# For a normal matrix $A$ with two real eigenvalues, how do I show that $(A - \lambda_1 I)(A - \lambda_2I)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is a normal matrix and the only eigenvalues of $A$ are both real ($\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$) (the algebraic multiplicities are unknown).
How do I prove that $(A - \lambda_1 I)(A - \lambda_2I)=0$, where I is the identity matrix?
I have tried using properties of normal matrices but have not been able to get that this product is zero.

Comment: Hint: Normal matrices are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is normal, $A$ is diagonalizable.  Write $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.  The eigenvalues of $A$ and $D$ are the same: $\lambda_1$ with some multiplicity and $\lambda_2$ with some multiplicity.

Note that (since scalars and the identity commute with everything)
\begin{align*}
(A - \lambda_1 I)(A - \lambda_2 I) &= P(D - \lambda_1 I)P^{-1}P(D - \lambda_2 I)P^{-1}  \\
    &= P(D - \lambda_1 I)(D - \lambda_2 I)P^{-1}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
In the first parenthesized factor, every row and column of $D$ that previously contained a copy of the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is made into a zero row and column.  Likewise, the rows and columns that contained $\lambda_2$ in the second parenthesized factor.  Thus, the product of the two parenthesized factors is zero.